# Python Frozenset

Tags: python, string, set, frozenset

I am using frozenset and I would like to avoid the output containing 'frozenset'. For example, I have

```
x = [frozenset([item]) for item in Set]

Output: frozenset(['yes']) => frozenset(['red', 'blue'])
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What is your expected output then?

Comment: I would just like (['yes']) => (['red', 'blue']). Essentially omitting 'frozenset'.

Comment: Why? What's the problem with seeing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by creating a subclass of `frozenset` and overriding its `__repr__` method:

```
class MyFrozenSet(frozenset):
    def __repr__(self):
        return '([{}])'.format(', '.join(map(repr, self)))
...     
>>> lst = [['yes'], ['red', 'blue']]
>>> [MyFrozenSet(x) for x in lst]
[(['yes']), (['blue', 'red'])]
```

Comment: you don't need a class to do - using a class seems overkill to me. and overriding `__repr__` like this breaks the semantics of what `__repr__` is expected to do.

Comment: *"If at all possible, [`__repr__`] should look like a valid Python expression that could be used to recreate an object with the same value (given an appropriate environment). If this is not possible, a string of the form `<...some useful description...>` should be returned."*